# Binding CheckBoxList to a Generic List

Tags: c#, asp.net, data-binding, checkboxlist

How to bind a CheckBoxList to a generic list object. This sample code should work for the purpose:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Works well with the datatable as a data source
    //DataTable _entityList = new DataTable();
    //_entityList.Columns.Add("Id", typeof(int));
    //_entityList.Columns.Add("ProductName", typeof(string));
    //_entityList.Rows.Add(new object[] { 1, "First" });
    //_entityList.Rows.Add(new object[] { 2, "Second" });

    // Doesn't work with the generic list as a data source
    List<MyProduct> _entityList = new List<MyProduct>();
    _entityList.Add(new MyProduct(1, "First"));
    _entityList.Add(new MyProduct(2, "Second"));

    cblProducts.DataSource = _entityList;
    cblProducts.DataTextField = "ProductName";
    cblProducts.DataValueField = "Id";
    cblProducts.DataBind();
}

public class MyProduct
{
    public int Id;
    public string ProductName;
    public bool selected;

    public MyProduct(int id, string desc, bool slctd)
    {
        this.Id = id;
        this.ProductName = desc;
        this.selected = slctd;
    }

    public MyProduct()
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
    }
}
```

But it is throwing a run time exception:

**DataBinding: 'Test.MyProduct' does not contain a property with the name 'ProductName'.**

What am I missing? I tried google the topic but failed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change your fields to properties:

```
public class MyProduct
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string ProductName { get; set; }
   public bool selected { get; set; }

   ...
}
```